# MySQL vs PHP query performance issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, cakephp

I have a sql query that runs in like 2 seconds in mysql (Navicat) and it runs through 600,000 locations returning all the table data and calculates the distance between a lat and long that I put in.

The SQL is something like this:

```
select *, 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - 
radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM places 
GROUP BY places.user_id
HAVING distance > 0
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10;
```

In the above query 37 and -122 are passed into the query as lat and long.

When I run this in Navicat, it's 2 seconds, but it takes minutes in Cakephp or straight php using mysql_query().

Why does this occur and how do I fix it?

I'm running both MySQL and Apache locally on a Win7 4GB box running XAMPP.

Comment: 1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/spatial-extensions.html 2. debug

Comment: Can You provide EXPLAIN EXTENDED [your query]? Can You confirm that the query runs in 2 seconds by doing: 1. SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE [rest of Your query]?

Comment: `mysql_query`? Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: yes i'm not using mysql_query, just for simple testing! I'm actually using Cakephp's $this->query. But both my test script which is straight PHP and my Cakephp are slow while the SQL script ran in like 2 to 4 seconds with NO CACHE. Why?

Comment: even taking 2 seconds is 2 seconds is uncomfortably long for a SQL query. You have got suitable indexes, right?

Comment: Are you specifying `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` as the host address for the server? I have seen situations where the routing table is wrong and using a machine's LAN IP rather than loopback causes all the data to be round-tripped out to the network and back, and if you were on a slow/lossy network (i.e. wireless) this would add considerably to the time it takes to return the results - although I still wouldn't expect it to be minutes. Can you show your PHP code? I'm thinking something else is the problem here and the query duration is a symptom, but not the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to your table structure. If you have not already, I would highly recommend you create an index on `user_id` in the `places` table. This can make a surprising difference in execution time for complex queries.

Also, since it seems you are doing a fair amount of calculation in the query ( for distance ), you may benefit greatly from using the prepared statements feature in the mysqli or PDO extensions - instead of using the older, slower, less-safe, deprecated mysql extension.

This article helps explain the differences: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php

If you are already accustomed to the mysql extension, I would recommend switching to mysqli - their procedural syntax/API is almost identical ( the main difference is that you will need to provide the $connection_handle as the first argument in many functions, instead of it being the optional final argument ).

Navicat may be taking advantage of prepared statements, that may be your difference.